# Asp.net Web api2 impersonate on webClient call

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

we have a web api what has is how user account let's say `ApplicationPoolUser`
that used have access to the databases used by the api, etc which work fine.

but i'm trying to send a http get method on files on a remote server(sharepoint 2007) using `webClient`

here's what im using :

```
            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(Path.Combine(this.Document.path , Document.fileNameOriginal));
            Stream stream = null;

// WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name return 'ApplicationPoolUser'
                try
                {
                    WindowsIdentity wi = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
                    impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(wi.Token); 
// WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name return 'CurrentRequestingUser'

                WebClient client = new WebClient() { 
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache)
                };

                stream = client.OpenRead(uri);
 // OpenRead Authentified on sharepoint server has ApplicationPoolUser
            }
            catch(WebException ex)
            {
                HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if(webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                throw new GeneralException(Common.Enums.ExceptionMessage.NotFound, webResp.StatusDescription);
                else
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

is there a way to force the authentification on behalf of the user without turning asp.net Identity ON ? in the web.config / IIS site.

I dont want the whole code to execute has the impersonated user request just this small part ...

I did try to use httpClient instead by i've found that since httpclient start in a new thread, it will always use the application pool identity.

can i create the Negotiate Call myself and add it to the request ?

thank you.

**EDIT** : 
i have tried Removing all AuthenticationManager except Kerberos, and the request still use NTLM for authentication, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You should not ask a new question inside an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple factors, which can make an impersonation or to be precise a delegation of the user credentials impossible.

1) if you are using asynchronous methods (directly or not) you might experience a problem with flowing the identity. You can check, if that might be an problem with the following call:

```
 System.Security.SecurityContext.IsWindowsIdentityFlowSuppressed();
```

This should return `false` - if not you can use this as a reference: [Calling an async WCF Service while being impersonated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628328/calling-an-async-wcf-service-while-being-impersonated)

2) You have to enable constrained delegation for the executing account. You have a so called Kerberos double hop scenario. You have to allow the Sharepoint user to act as another user or else impersonate() will not succeed as expected.

Comment: System.Security.SecurityContext.IsWindowsIdentityFlowSuppressed(); return false before and after the impersonation()

Comment: This is an System wide setting, which might prevent Impersonation, it should be false. But you still need the delegation permission.